# Is .Include still working on Entity Framework Core & .NET 5.0?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, .net-5

When I try to write this code `.Include` is not recognized

```
dbContext.Field.Include(i => ..);
```

*Example:*

[image: .Include not appearing]

Comment: have you added **using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;** or **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query**?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Nope. You are right, must be added in the method where .Include is used. Thanks.

Comment: ok, I added it as answer. In EF6 it was [System.Data.Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include?view=entity-framework-5.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=entity-framework-6.2.0) that was often forgot to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you miss the using statement so that the Include Extension is found.

So add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` to get access to [Include](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/b706ce66eb67f10f20426cb496331781c0c9ddb0/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2437).